# What's the concept of *worker role* in Windows Azure cloud?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

As I understood, it's long running process in server. Can it cover long-running program instance like online game server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can think of a worker role as a Windows Service or a Unix Daemon. It is, as you say, a perpetually executing process (although it may be in a wait state for a large portion of the time, but that's for you to decide).

Essentially it can run any code you'd like to write.

It can react to outside stimuli e.g. by polling from the Azure Queue service, but can also open communication channels, query databases, etc.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like what I've been found. Does it support direct/low-latency TCP/UDP connections?

Comment: Yes, though it sits behind a load balancer - so you can open ports on it and add multiple machines behind the url as you need.  You can also communicate between the machines in the azure data center within you roles if you need to.

Comment: @Jason, does it mean my packets have to pass through load-balancer instead of direct communication to specific machine with IP address? If it is, its latency seem to be high.

Comment: I've not noticed any latency.

Comment: Windows Azure roles support TCP connections, both to/from the outside world and between role instances. UDP is only supported when using Azure Connect (Azure's software VPN). You cannot expose a public or internal endpoint supporting UDP.

When communicating between role instances, traffic does not go through the load balancer.