# Install service in windows azure

Tags: azure, windows-services, installation

I would like to know that is there any way to install the windows service on Azure environment? Or is there any alternate way of doing the same?

Comment: You can create a worker role and try to deploy on your azure

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly what you need in Azure is a Worker Role, similar question on Stackoverflow: [What's the concept of *worker role* in Windows Azure cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335789/whats-the-concept-of-worker-role-in-windows-azure-cloud)

Check out the this blog post 'Migrating Windows Service to Azure Worker Role'
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joseph_fultz/archive/2010/04/02/migrating-windows-service-to-azure-worker-role-image-conversion-example-using-storage.aspx

Also look at the Windows Azure Training Kit for code & usage sample for Worker Roles in Azure
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8396

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Another potential option is to use StartUp tasks to install a windows service in either a Web or a Worker Role.

Here is an MSDN article - although it seems a little short on the details.

[How to Define Startup Tasks for a Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx)

Basically you will need to be sure that the installer is copied during the deployment and create a cmd file to execute the installer. Then add a Startup task element to the service definition XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to add along with the other answers:

1. You can install Services with Web or Worker Role through the Startup Task
2. Alternatively you can also run a process with elevated privilege through the Task Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to install a windows service on VM running Windows Server 2012 R2:

- start your VM in Windows Azure Console and connect to it with Remote Desktop Connector
- map your storage as a new drive in your VM:

  net use z: \mystorage.file.core.windows.net\endoint /u:myusername verylongkeythatendswith==

Storage key can be found in your Azure Management Console -> Storages -> Manage Access Keys

- copy all the necessary installation files to the mapped storage (copy&paste)
- copy nssm to a local drive (not z: as it uses MAFS file system and that cannot be accessed with low-level windows API commands)
- Create a .bat file with the following entries

> set username=xxx
>   set password=yyy
>   call d:\nssm install "My service"
>   "%programfiles%\PathToService\myservice.exe" "-p 8677"
>       d:\nssm set "My service" ObjectName "%username%" "%password%"
>       sc failure "My service" actions= restart/60000/restart/60000/restart/60000 reset= 240
>       d:\nssm start "My service"

Username and password should be the ones you used to create the VM.

- run the script. The service should be visible in your services list.

Enjoy!

PS : I used [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/download) to simplify the service deployment.